# Lead Assignment issue

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

The issue was Leads from outbound sources do not need to follow lead assignment rule, they need to be assigned to the User who created it only, how can we do this.

I have tried by adding the extra filter like source not equal to outbound then they were assigning to a Queue which was the default owner.

Comment: "Assign the outbound Lead to the Lead who created it"? This statement is quite confusing. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Whenever a lead is coming from outbound sources, it should not get assigned based on the assignment rule, it should be assigned to the person who created the Lead itself.

Comment: why do you have the default owner setup then?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

Add a new rule entry to your assignment rules:

**Criteria**

- `source = Outbound`
- Check the box `Do not reassign owner`
- Make the rule order = 1 so it executes first
- SAVE

This will ensure the lead's owner is the same as the running user (who would be the user that created it)

Comment: Thank You soo much, it worked

Comment: Great news!. As a service to the Community, given this worked for you; mark the answer as accepted (see checkmark)